# Prestashop api - How to get the current cart contents

Tags: web-services, shopping-cart, prestashop

I'm new to Prestashop, I cant find examples anywhere of how to get the current cart contents. I can get a list of all carts, but how do I get the current users cart?

Answer (score 11):

it is easy and simple. I am considering you are using PS 1.5.x

In controllers other than cart controller

```
  $cart = new Cart($this->context->cookie->id_cart);
```

or in an class

```
 $context = new Context();
 $cart = new Cart($context->cookie->id_cart);
```

Now the $cart is an object, and it has all the current cart data.

You can also get the cart products by calling getProducts like below

```
 $cartProducts = $cart->getProducts();
```

Hope this will help.

Please note that code is not tested and is just a sample code for your idea.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

For **PS 1.4.X** you can get using `getProducts()`

```
$product_array = $this->getProducts();

print_r($product_array);
```

Example :

```
public function getSubTotal() {
    $product_array = $this->getProducts();

    foreach($product_array as $product_item) {
            $sub_total += $product_item['price'] * $product_item['cart_quantity'];
    }

    return $sub_total;
}
```